# CORS issue in react app, can't upload images

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, cors

I'm using laravel for api and react js for front-end thing. But whenever I'm trying to upload images to the server, I'm getting CORS issue.

```
'api-url has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.'
```

sometimes it works but sometimes not. Is there any permanent solution?

I'm using following plugin for cors.
https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors

cors.php

```
return[
    'paths' => ['api/*'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => false,]
```

Comment: It depends a lot from the configuration of your backend server. do you have access to it?

Comment: Have you configured `CORS` at the back-end?

Comment: I have access to the server. what should I change to make it work?

Comment: You need to define the `CORS` policy on server. [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: @NazmulHasan now which request works and which doesn't?

Comment: /api/v1/admin/advertisements, this is a post request. It doesn't work. sometimes it works from localhost. but sometimes it doesn't even work from localhost.

Comment: @NazmulHasan check the laravel `logs` and let me know the `errors`. Try clear the logs first and then request again

Comment: one more thing to mention, if I use postman, everything is fine. But in react I'm sending base64 image to server.

Comment: Because the `POSTMAN` doesn't enforce `CORS` while browser does

Comment: @BasheerKharoti I just checked the logs, but I only got following that matches with cors
"/var/www/prm/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php(50): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))"

Comment: Share the full logs `kopy.io`

Comment: @BasheerKharoti https://kopy.io/6cJWJ

Comment: Share the `app\Http\Kernel.php` global middleware array

Comment: Also, are you using `JWT` or `Larvael's` default auth?

Comment: @BasheerKharoti kernel.php  https://ideone.com/pe8FJ3

Comment: @BasheerKharoti also I'm using jwt

Comment: ok cool just move this to top in the array `\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class`

Comment: Also, share your routes file as well

Comment: @BasheerKharoti here is the route: https://ideone.com/g4Y0Wv     using only this as api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the docs you are missing the following in your code:

> If possible, use a route group with CSRF protection disabled. Otherwise you can disable CSRF for certain requests in `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken`:

```
protected $except = [
 'api/*'
]
```

And on more thing is that you should move the `CORS` middleware to the top of the array

> To allow CORS for all your routes, add the HandleCors middleware at the top of the $middleware property of `app/Http/Kernel.php` class:

```
protected $middleware = [
 \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
];
```